# Prove $X_T$ is integrable if $X$ is a supermartingale, $T$ is stopping time and other conditions

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, martingales, stopping-times

Let $X = ({X_n})_{n \ge 1}$ be a/an $(\{\mathscr{F_n}\}_{n \ge 1}, \mathbb{P})$-supermartingale in the filtered probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \{\mathscr{F_n}\}_{n \ge 1}, \mathbb{P})$.

Prove $X_T$ is integrable if $\exists K \ge 0$ s.t. $$|X_n - X_{n-1}| \le K \ \forall n \ge 1$$

and $T$ is a stopping time w/ finite expectation.

So far all I was able to show is that $X_{T \wedge n}$ is integrable and $E[X_T] \le E[X_0]$.

Hints pls?

Comment: This follows directly from optional stopping theorem.

Comment: @Math1000 It's what I'm [trying to prove](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1519702/).

Comment: @Did Elsewhere I think. How about you just point out and explain what is wrong w/ my answer instead of pointing out that errors exist? I feel discouraged to answer or ask. I think I and math SE could benefit if you would do that. If I am merely pointed out the existence of errors, I don't find that very helpful as I would be reviewing again and again w/o seeing what is wrong. I find that kind of condescending

Comment: @Did What makes you think that I do not care? Do I not thank you for your feedback and comments on my answers, questions and other comments? What I mean by that is point out a specific inequality or part. For example, '$\lim X_{T \wedge n} = \lim [(T \wedge n) K + X_0]$ is wrong. We have only $\le$'.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$$|X_T| = |\lim_{n \to \infty} X_{T \wedge n}| = \lim_{n \to \infty} | X_{T \wedge n}|$$

Consider $X_{T \wedge n}$:

$$X_{T \wedge n} = \sum_{k=1}^{T \wedge n} (X_k - X_{k-1}) + X_0$$

$$\to |X_{T \wedge n}| = |\sum_{k=1}^{T \wedge n} (X_k - X_{k-1}) + X_0|$$

$$ \le |\sum_{k=1}^{T \wedge n} (X_k - X_{k-1})| + |X_0|$$

$$ \le \sum_{k=1}^{T \wedge n} |X_k - X_{k-1}| + |X_0|$$

$$ \le \sum_{k=1}^{T \wedge n} K + |X_0|$$

$$ = (T \wedge n) K + |X_0|$$

Thus, we have

$$|X_T| \le \lim [(T \wedge n) K + |X_0|]$$

$$\le [\lim (T \wedge n)] K + |X_0| \le TK + |X_0|$$

Hence,

$$E[|X_T|] \le E[TK + |X_0|]$$

$$\le K\underbrace{E[T]}_{ < \infty} + \underbrace{E[|X_0|]}_{< \infty \ \because \ \text{X is a supermart}} < \infty$$

Comment: This mixes horribly upper bounds on some real number $x$ and on $|x|$.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @Did. Would you mind telling me w/c part exactly contains mix ups so that I might edit out the mistakes?

Comment: @Did I don't understand your first comment. Do you mind pointing to a specific inequality in my answer that is wrong and explaining why it is wrong? I have reviewed my answer several times and see nothing wrong

Comment: As already mentioned, $x\leqslant y$ does not imply $|x|\leqslant|y|$.

Comment: @Did thanks ^-^ time to edit answer. I don't see how your first comment meant that though.

Comment: Edited. Thanks again, @Did ^-^ If there's anything wrong, pls let me know