# $X_T = \lim_{n \to \infty} X_{T \wedge n}$ if X is a supermartingale and T is a finite a.s. stopping time?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, probability-theory, martingales, stopping-times

Given a filtered probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \{\mathscr{F_n}\}, \mathbb{P})$,

let $X = (X_n)_{n \geq 0}$ be a $(\{\mathscr{F_n}\}, \mathbb{P})$-supermartingale and $T$ be a finite $\mathbb{P}$-a.s. stopping time.

When can we say that $$X_T = \lim_{n \to \infty} X_{T \wedge n} \ \text{a.s.} \tag{*}$$?

It seems that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} T \wedge n = T \tag{**}$$ but I don't think that's enough.

I think I can say that

$$X_{T\wedge n} = ( \ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 1_{\{T=k\}} X_k \ ) + 1_{T\ge n} X_n$$

If so, I think we have

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} X_{T\wedge n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} ( \ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 1_{\{T=k\}} X_k \ ) + \lim_{n \to \infty} 1_{T\ge n} X_n$$

$$ = \lim_{n \to \infty} ( \ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 1_{\{T=k\}} X_k \ ) + \lim_{n \to \infty} 1_{T\ge n} \lim_{n \to \infty} X_n$$

$$ = \lim_{n \to \infty} ( \ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 1_{\{T=k\}} X_k \ ) + (0) \lim_{n \to \infty} X_n \text{(*)}$$

$$ = \lim_{n \to \infty} ( \ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 1_{\{T=k\}} X_k \ )$$

$$ = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 1_{\{T=k\}} X_k = X_T$$

(*) I guess I need to assume that $\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n$ exists. Is that it? $X_T = \lim_{n \to \infty} X_{T \wedge n}$ a.s. provided $\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n$ exists a.s.?

---

Edit: I found this link that seems to suggest $(*)$ and $(**)$:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix $\omega \in \Omega$ such that $T(\omega)<\infty$. Then there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $T(\omega) \leq N$. In particular,

$$T(\omega) \wedge n = T(\omega) \qquad \text{for all } n \geq N.$$

This implies

$$X_{T \wedge n}(\omega) = X_{T}(\omega)  \qquad \text{for all }n \geq N.$$

Hence, obviously,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} X_{T \wedge n}(\omega) = X_{T}(\omega).$$

Since this holds for almost all $\omega \in \Omega$, this proves

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} X_{T \wedge n} = X_T \quad \text{a.s.}$$

**Remark:** Note that this argument applies to any stochastic process $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$; we do not need the supermartingale property.

Comment: Thanks saz. It's supposed to be T right?

Comment: 'Since this holds for almost all ' --> Why almost all only?

Comment: @BCLC Yeah, thanks. It holds (only) for almost all $\omega$ because you   (only) assumed that $T$ is $\mathbb{P}$-a.s. finite, i.e. $\mathbb{P}(T=\infty)=0$.

Comment: saz, I added almost surely's to your answer. How do you find them?

Comment: @BCLC There is no need to add "a.s." in my answer since I fixed $\omega \in \Omega$ at the beginning of my proof. Please refrain from editing my answer.

Comment: Oh okay, I get it now. a.s. is needed only in the beginning or something like that. Sorry. I was thinking you could just rollback. I didn't expect any part of my editing to be right. Thanks saz ^-^

Comment: @DanielFischer if saz intended to remove all the a.s.'s, e could've just rolled back. If indeed $T < \infty$, why is there a need for a.s. later on?

Comment: @BCLC Perhaps saz didn't think of the rollback option. In the first part of the answer, a fixed $\omega$ (such that $T(\omega) < \infty$) is considered. It doesn't make sense to write "a.s." there. At the end, something is said about the _functions_ $X_{T \wedge n}$ and $X_T$, so we say something about all $\omega$ simultaneously. Since we don't have a premise about every single $\omega\in \Omega$, but only that the condition holds almost surely, we can also only assert the equality $\lim X_{T\wedge n} = X_T$ almost surely.

Comment: @BCLC Just stop editing my answers; no matter the rollback option. If you find a mistake/typo, then write a comment and I'll take care of it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @saz No. Thank you. Sorry again

Comment: @saz, I don't mean to open a new question for this so I hope it's okay to ask here, what happens if $T= \infty$ a.s.? The arguments you provided seem to work exactly the same then, is there a problem in that case with $X_T$ being well defined?

Comment: @Spaced Well, if $T(\omega)=\infty$ then $X_T(\omega) = X_{\infty}(\omega)$ is not well-defined, right?So, yes, it's a problem. If, however, we assume additionally that the limit $X_{\infty} := \lim_{n \to \infty} X_n$ exists almost surely, then everything works fine.